# Finding Service unavailaibity

Tags: c++, service

I have written a service which is dependent on other other service. Usually if other service timeouts or not responding then my service response time is affected. Is there any way I can find out that for how much time the service outage is so taht i can wait for that many seconds and then retry.

Thanks,
Shruti

Comment: Service and C++ I can't see the relation. Are you referring to Android Service or something?

Comment: Are we talking about a Windows Service?

Answer (score 0):

In general: no, it's not possible, you probably shouldn't even know where the service is that you're accessing.
In your implementation: who knows, you might be lucky.
**The normal way would be to wait for some time and then throw an exception.**